# OpenCV 4.1.1 not loaded on my Android device

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to make an Android Studio Project which has a native cpp code that created with a CMake based process.

Android Studio version 3.4.2, build tools version 28.0.3 and I don't know there is any problem with it but my module name is openCv411.

The project is very simple; it is processing the real-time camera video in Android device, but there is a problem that I can't see in my Project.

Please write me which files or codes I have to share with you.

Note: Sync and build are successfully.

Comment: I wrote a turorial/sample application for setting up native OpenCV 4.1.0 with Android on this [Github repository](https://github.com/VlSomers/native-opencv-android-template). You can use this project as a starting point as it does what you're trying to achieve: apply a filter in real time on a live camera feed. Hope it helps.

Comment: @vSomers Is changing native-lib.cpp enough to do this?

Comment: Yes you can just add you opencv image processing pipeline into native-lib.cpp and it should work!

Comment: @vSomers can you look at my newest question, it is about your app. https://stackoverflow.com/q/57822746/11848528

Comment: Not at home for now, will have a look at it asap